# как вставить пользовательское videoId Youtube API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, youtube-api

есть сайт(asp.net core mvc), где пользователь вставляет в окошко ссылку на ютуб видео, после нажимает на кнопку и видео появляется. вот только если в функцию onYouTubeIframeAPIReady (функция создания ютуб плеера и iframe) как-то передать videoId, или в самой функции через document.getElementById("userUrl").value достать url видео и потом из него достать id видоса и вставить в свойство, то выдается ошибка. кнопка вообще не хочет реагировать

```
//videoSrc - кнопка, при нажатие на которую и до
document.getElementById("videoSrc").addEventListener("click", function () {
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
});
```

```
//userUrl - textbox, куда и вводится url видео
var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var videoUrl = document.getElementById("userUrl").value;
        var videoId = getVideoId(videoUrl);
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: videoId,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            }
        });
    }
```

```
// Функция для получения video id из url
function getVideoId(url) {
    var videoId = "";
    if (url.indexOf("youtube.com") !== -1) {
        videoId = url.split("v=")[1];
    } else if (url.indexOf("youtu.be") !== -1) {
        videoId = url.split(".be/")[1];
    }
    return videoId;
}
```

буду рада любой помощи